# Android 7 - Child/Parent app behavior

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

We've a App which works as a parent app "A", we invokes a child app "B" using url scheme (installed in same device) from parent app "A", then push both the app to background. 
Tap icon of parent app "A" and it launches to same page of child app "B".
This behavior we're seeing in Android 7 only, below Android it's opening Parent App "A" only. So just wanted to know that if it's a expected behavior of android 7?

Comment: There are three points you need to clarify first: 1) What did you expect to see instead? 2) What happens below Android 7.0? 3) How did you implement these parent and child apps? (a.k.a. post come code)

Comment: @NecipAllef, update the question, I'm using url scheme to invoke child app. Also, nothing is expected but wanted to know that if it's known behavior of Android 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I come to know that it was not device specific though it's depend that how we're opening child app.

If want to child app separation from parent app, just place below code when invoking child app.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```